# Old black & white horror movie (maybe on Shock Theater) where a man escapes a mansion then a lightning rod impales him

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, ghost

I watched a movie in the mid 1970s as a child and would really love to see it again with my 13 year old son. It could have been on Shock Theater. It was a very old black and white movie, possibly 30s to late 50s.

There's a man that is in an old huge mansion and he can't seem to escape it. He goes from room to room and sees visions of old Victorian people dancing as ghosts. Once he finally escapes the old haunted mansion. It's stormy outside and lightning hits the metal weather vane/rod on the roof. This strike of lightning sends the metal rod to the ground and it impales the man, leaving him standing there with a rod through his body.

Scared me to death at about 9 or 10 years old. Does anyone know the title?

Comment: The lightning rod part brings to mind a [scene from _The Omen_ (1976)](https://youtu.be/IJS5p_l5Czg?t=78) (R.I.P. the Second Doctor). The other details don't match, though.

Comment: @LogicDictates It also brings to mind the *Saturday Night Live* send up of *The Omen*!

Answer (score 8):

Your description reminds me of the 1964 film [*Castle of Blood*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057993/). Although the film does not match all of your memories, the basics are present.

The main character was a man who accepted a wager to spend the Night of the Dead inside a haunted house: his reluctance to escape stemmed from his determination to see the wager through. Inside the mansion he encountered many ghosts, and witnessed them reenacting the ends of their lives, but the ghosts were also vampires that wanted his blood.

He escaped the mansion before dawn and made his way out of the grounds through the main gate, where he paused. The gate swung closed just behind him. The character was not impaled by a falling lightning rod, but by a spike on the the gate as it swung shut. The dead protagonist remained standing there, his body supported by the iron spike.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind reply! I'm now 57 years old so the memories could be meshing together from two films, yet it seems not in my mind. I think Castle of Blood may be just what I'm remembering and I'll definitely watch it tonight. Can't thank you enough!! Greg

Answer (score 3):

Your description of the specific scene with the *lightning rod struck by lightning, then impaling the protagonist directly below* is from The Omen (1976).

It's not black and white, but the tones are very subdued and the main character (a priest) is in a traditional frock.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I know the movie was black and white........yet my brother reminded me we only had a Black and White TV back then as well. LOL ;) I'll watch Castle of Blood first and then maybe The Omen again. Much appreciate your help!  Greg

Comment: @GregKelly - I remember watching snooker on a black and white set. Not fun